# Need an awk script to prepend missing zeroes from Solaris mac address

Tags: awk, solaris, mac-address

I'm using awk to grab a specific mac address:

```
ifconfig rtls0 | awk '/ether/ {print $2}'
```

Simple enough (I'm new to awk). But Solaris strips leading zeros from the mac address so I need to grab the text from each entry and if the string length is 1 then prepend a 0 and continue.

It doesn't *have* to be awk. Sed would be fine as well. I'm unsure what the most appropriate tool would be in this situation as there are a lot of options.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the output of `ifconfig rtls0` look like (or at least the line in question)?

Comment: ether a:2c:ab:dd:75:31

And after the awk command it's simply the mac address

Comment: To complete to see if I understood properly, you get ether `a:ab:c:12:3:31` and you wish to get `0a:ab:0c:12:03:31` am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Exemple:

```
echo 'ether a:2c:ab:3:75:31' |  awk '/ether/ { nb=split($2,arr,":"); for (i=1;i<=nb;i++) { a=sprintf("%s:%02x",a,"0x"arr[i]) }; sub(/^:/,"",a); print a"\n" }'
```

give as output:

```
0a:2c:ab:03:75:31
```

what is done in awk line by line:

```
/ether/ { # if line contains ether
  nb=split($2,arr,":") # split the second field on : into arr, and store the number of parts in nb
  for (i=1;i<=nb;i++) { # loop with an integer until nb
    a=sprintf("%s:%02x",a,"0x"arr[i]) # concatenate into 'a' the actual field 'arr[i]' given as hex with "0x"arr[i] into a 0 padded 2 digit hex number (%02x). More detail out of this
  }; 
  sub(/^:/,"",a); print a"\n" # suppress the leading : and print the result.
}
```

More detail on the sprintf part:

- `sprintf` use printf format to return a string
- `"%s:%02x"` is the desired format, a string `%s` then `:` and then a 2digit hex number, padded with 0 `%02x`
- `a,"0x"arr[i]`  gives the arguments to the format, %s will be filled with `a` variable and `"0x"arr[i]` will give to `%02x`what is in the array, forcing it to be interpreted as an hex number by preceding the text with `0x`

I hope its clear enought ;)

Comment: You do not need to declare variable in `awk`, so you can remove: `BEGIN { a="" }`

Comment: Thanks @jtone forgot to remove it.